# Website hosted by easyPHP on Windows 7 can't be accessed by other computers on the same LAN

Tags: windows-7, connection, easyphp

I set up a web server in my Windows 7 with easyPHP. The website works fine when you browse to http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/. But, you can't open the site from another computer in my LAN. My local IP is in the 10.x.x.x range. I can ping other machines on the same LAN. But, I cannot browse to 10.x.x.x from my own or any other PC.

I am currently easyPHP on Windows 7 with the firewall turned off on my private network.

P.S.: I fixed one problem: In `httpd.conf` I changed `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` to `Listen 80`. Now browsing the page using localhost works fine, but using 10.x.x.x I get an `Access forbidden` message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been fixed:

The problem was in httpd.conf:

1) I did change my Alias

```
<Directory "C:/Users/...">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
</Directory>
```

2)
Listen key from Listen 127.0.0.1:80 to Listen 80

Comment: If this solves the problem, please click on the ✓ symbol to accept this as the answer.

Comment: After searching all over google the point _2_ from your answer solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Listen port to 80 in the http.conf file allowed me to access my computer as a web server from another computer.  The default file displayed was in my "EasyPHP/www" folder.  When I moved content thier, it was displayed.

When I updated the "Directory" section of the of the http.conf file (along with the Listen port change) I was able to see other directories I specified there.